# Ignoring files containing no period in git

Tags: regex, git

I want to ignore all the files in my git repository whose name does not contain any '.' (period). How to make git ignore them?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as the .gitignore file uses a shell glob sytnax.

Comment: What is your requirement, what is the cause for that?

Comment: My compiler is creating executables based on the name of the source file. For example if I compile some source file named xyz.cpp, it creates an executable file named xyz. I don't want git to keep track of these executable files.

Comment: Generate into a folder, ignore the folder content.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: you're correct that Git uses shell globs, which are too weak to do this in one step, but `.gitignore` allows negative declarations and multiple steps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ignore everything: `*`
2. Un-ignore directories, so that Git will look inside directories: `!*/`
3. Un-ignore files with at least one dot: `!*.*`

The resulting `.gitignore` consists of those three lines, in that order:

```
$ cat .gitignore
*
!*/
!*.*
$ git ls-files --other
.gitignore
foo
foo.txt
sub/bar
sub/bar.y
$ git status --short -uall
?? .gitignore
?? foo.txt
?? sub/bar.y
```

(While this does work, it may not be the best overall strategy: as [Yunnosch suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620968/ignoring-files-containing-no-period-in-git#comment80193872_46620968), it might be better, strategically, to put the generated binaries elsewhere.)